# Need help understanding the MVC design pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am trying to find a ood example of MVC design pattern in java.

This is what i understood from reading about it, please correct me if I am wrong:

I have the Model part which is the logic behind the program, let's say if we have a phonebook, so adding and removing contact from the Array will be the model.

The Gui is the view and it contains buttons that upon clicking them, the model is changing.

What I am trying to undersand what is the controller part, is it the ActionListeners? how to you seperate those modules in practice.

thank you

Comment: To comment specifically on what you posted, you're not quite right.  The array and the data within it is the model (i.e. the state of the program).  You may think of the model as time-independent, it just is what it is at any given time.  The code that adds and removes data from the array and is aware of the state of the array over time is the controller.

Comment: check this http://www.infoq.com/articles/Nacked-MVC, http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used MVC for a long time and find it to be a fantastic mechanism for approaching software design.  My advice while you're learning it is to make *everything* a controller at first.  In other words, create a class that has members that contain state (model) and also members that display and manipulate that state (views).  Make the functions of your class take input from the views, modify the data, and then update the views (controller).

This obviously doesn't embody the separation that the design pattern intends, but it will help you learn quickly to identify what is a clear view component and what is a clear model component.  Then take some time to separate out into separate files/objects independent model objects (which is easiest) and later independent view objects.

After you do this for a project or two, the separation will begin to be more natural and obvious and as you start *new* projects you'll know before you start writing code (design phase) what sorts of things go where.

From personal experience I think you're more apt to overthink things and do too much work if you try to categorize everything without some real development experience first.  You'll find if you spend some time writing a project in a natural way and then breaking things down as you go or afterwords that it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is usually the part of MVC that people have the most trouble defining. In your example, it's the bit that loads and manipulates the phonebook, as well as the bit that selects which view to use.

Answer (score -2):

In your example, the two seem to converge.

However, take for example the following scenario.
A factory-wide internal contact book.
In this scenario (let's assume that), most users can't add contacts to the address book.
Only the Human-Resource department can add a new contact (=employee) to the list.
We now have 3 truly separate pieces of code:

1. **The GUI (seen by regular employees)**
   This is a simple list, that always presents the whole list of employees/mail-addresses.
   The viewing employee, has absolutely no control over the list - he/she just views it.
   The employee could ***change the appearance*** of the list (e.g. sort it by last name, change font).
   Any such change is internal to the viewer, and is not recorded or supervised by the model or controller.
2. **The controller (accessible only by the HR department)**
   This can be another GUI, but with the ***ability to make changes*** to the list state (e.g. add/remove employees).
   If you wish to take this to the extreme, assume it's a shell-like window.
   When an HR employee wishes to add a new employee, he/she types into the shell:
   "ADD 'john smith' johns2@internalMail"
3. **The model - preserving state, and overseeing state-changes.**
   This is as you described. It ***performs the necessary logic*** of the process.
   For example, it won't add an employee that was already added and so on.

The "problem" with your scenario, is that it's probably not a classic one for MVC.
MVC implies anti-symmetry. That is, NOT all "viewers" are alike, some are "special"/admin and have additional benefits over "regular" viewers.

Hope it clears things.

Comment: This isn't right. In MVC all application users can only ever see views. There would be multiple views, and the HR department would have access to some additional ones, saying that the HR department gets access to a controller isn't MVC.